# right-justified sections in columns with paracol

Tags: resume, paracol

I’m new to LaTeX and was trying to make a resume.  Within my resume I have a section and in that section I want two columns.  Within these two columns there will be both a subsection and a subsubsection.  I need the subsection and the subsubsection in the second column to be right-justified. I’m using the `paracol` package to achieve the column environment.

Here is the MWE code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{paracol}

\titleformat{\section}
{\huge\bfseries\lowercase} 
{} 
{0em} 
{} 
[\titlerule]

\titleformat{\subsection}
{}
{$\bullet$}
{0.25em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{}
{}
{0.8em}
{}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{\begin{center}


{\huge\bfseries\theauthor}

\vspace{0.25em}

example address --- example@email.com
\end{center}
}


\newcommand{\datedsubsection}[2]{ \subsection[#1] {#1 \hfill #2} }

\begin{document}

\title{R\'esum\'e}
\author{John Doe}
\maketitle



\section{example section}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    
    \switchcolumn[0]
    
    \subsection{example subsection 1}
    
    
    
    
    \subsubsection{example subsubsection 1}
    
    \switchcolumn[1]


    
    \subsection{example subsection 2} 
    
    \subsubsection{example subsubsection 2} 
    

\end{paracol}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of what this code produces[image: example pic]

I just need the second column to be right justified.  I've tried using the `flushright` environment but that will only yield something like this: [image: example pic when using flushright]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your example is not complete to compile. And is there some reason that you must use title to do such thing?

Comment: The ```\documentclass{article}``` was left out of the preamble.  My apologies, I've made the edit and I think it should compile now. To be honest I was following an instructional video on making a CV and that is why the title is the way it is. I'm open to changing it.

Comment: If you just want a piece of text with some format, there is no need to use title.

Comment: I see, so instead of using subsections and subsubsections, I should just write it as text.